# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - Error

Tags: html, jquery, syntax-error

While running this little code tag on my .html file

```
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="./uploads/ESA 4/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>');
</script>
```

I am getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Error. I am not quite sure why I am getting this error. So how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is seeing `</script>` and matching it with the `<script>` tag, even though it's inside quotes.

To reduce the issue (eliminate the other parts):

```
<script>
    var x = "</script>";
</script>
```

gives the same error.

You can fix this by splitting the `"</script>"`, as in:

```
<script>
    var x = "</" + "script>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write('<script src="./uploads/ESA 4/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>'`
you are using quotations inside of, another quotatio... i think that is the problem...Thank you